# Working with panda dataframe column values and pasting in next row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am very new to Panda dataframe in Python. I am working on a code where the csv file structure looks like below:

```
Id, Title, Body, Tags, Date
1, First question, My first question, robot Python, 2015
2, Second question, My second question, C++ Python, 2015
3, Third question, My third question, Selenium, 2016
4, Fourth question, My fourth question, Java C++, 2016
```

I have exported this CSV to my python code using Panda library

I am trying to get the dataframe like below:

```
Id, Title, Body, Tags, Date
1, First question, My first question, robot, 2015
2, First question, My first question, Python, 2015
3, Second question, My second question, C++, 2015
4, Second question, My second question, Python, 2015
.......
```

Kindly let me know if there are any suitable way to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
df = df.drop(["Id"], axis=1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    aux = row
    for tag in row["Tags"].split():
        aux["Tags"] = tag
        df2 = df2.append(aux)
df2.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Where df is your dataframe and df2 is the updated one. You iterate over each row of the dataframe df and split the "Tags" value into as many tags as it may have (in your example the maximum number was 2 but I suppose you could have many more). You then append the row with each individual tag to the new dataframe df2.
(I drop the id and reset the index as it is keeping the original index values)

```
    Title,  Body,   Tags,   Date,
0   First question, My first question,  robot,  2015
1   First question, My first question,  Python, 2015
2   Second question,    My second question, C++,    2015
3   Second question,    My second question, Python, 2015
4   Third question, My third question,  Selenium,   2016
5   Fourth question,    My fourth question, Java,   2016
6   Fourth question,    My fourth question, C++,    2016
```

Answer (score -1):

it's best practice to provide the full code of what you are trying to do so we can fully help you.

I think what you are trying to do is simply replace some values.  You can use this structure.

```
df['column name'] = df['column name'].replace(['old value'],'new value')
```

So for your example.

```
df['Title'] = df['Title'].replace({'Second Question': 'First Question',
                                   'Second Question' : 'Third Question"}),
                                    inplace = True)
```

etc, etc.

Comment: He is trying to duplicate columns based on the Tags value, not rename the Title...